# Get the value of all span with in ul li

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to alert all span value which is with in all li one by one.

**View**

```
<ul class="cg-tag-list" >
        <li ng-repeat="tag in list">
           <span>{{tag}}</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

**Js**

```
angular.forEach($scope.tag, function (item) {
          //put your code here
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put alert inside function
use $scope.list instead of $scope.tag because it is undefined according to given code

```
angular.forEach($scope.list, function (item) {
          alert(item);
  });
```